# Flatten nested object Typescript

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects

I have a an interface,I need to write a function to flatten the object .I want the 'Phrase' in single tier object

```
 interface IRule {
  activationDate: number;
  contentSources: string[];
  createdBy: string | undefined;
  dateCreated: number;
  dateUpdated: number;
  publishFailed: boolean;
  name: string;
  ruleCustomFields: {
    CustomFields: {
      phrases: string[];
      warning: string;
    };
  };
  ruleId: string;
}
```

data:

```
 {
  "activationDate": 1664390668.694,
  "contentSources": [""],
  "createdBy": "iusername”,
  "dateCreated": 1664390668.694,
  "dateUpdated": 1664390668.694,
  "name": "charm",
  "publishFailed": false,
  "ruleCustomFields": {
    "CustomFields": {
      "phrases": ["fake-chrm"],
      "warning": "blocked"
    }
  },
  "ruleId": "1233",

}
```

I tried to pull phrases out but it throws error saying **'item.ruleCustomFields.CustomFields is undefined'**(I only need the first phrase in that array)

```
  const flatItems = rules.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    phrase: item.ruleCustomFields.CustomFields.phrases[0]
  }));
```

Comment: Unrelated problems: `publishFailed` and `ruleWarningLevel` are not defined in the interface.

Comment: my bad ,I missed it when typing the question,Updated now.Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: [Created a playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ajpntj?file=index.ts) and I am not able to reproduce it. You can check the console on the right side.

Comment: Please include your full code, preferably with a playground link and the intended result. I also don't get any errors https://tsplay.dev/mArR4W

Comment: Do all rules have CustomFields ? maybe try with null-check: `phrase: item.ruleCustomFields.CustomFields?.phrases[0] || ''`

Comment: @Jhilton thank you very much! handling the empty values worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not have only 1 rule, as you are doing a `map` operation.

Moving my comment here:

Do all rules have CustomFields?
I am guessing some values in the array has a `null` or `undefined` value which is what gives you the error.

It would be better to have a null-check as:

```js
phrase: item.ruleCustomFields.CustomFields?.phrases[0] || ''
```

Where the `?` operator will return null if value does not exists, and the `||` operator will make a nice empty string default to avoid `null` phrases.

Comment: The interface clearly says that CustomFields cannot be null. Either the interface needs to be updated or the backend API needs to respect the frontend interface.